# Хочу протестить действие функции подсчёта тасков(заданий) Python + pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Вот сама функция:

```
def count():  # type: (None) -> int
    """Return the number of tasks in db."""
    if _tasksdb is None:
        raise UninitializedDatabase()
    return _tasksdb.count()
```

А вот мой код:

```
tasks_to_try_2 = (Task('waked', 'brian', False),
                  Task('waked', 'briaN', False))

task_to_try_3 = (Task('Situp', 'slavik', True),
                 Task('SitUp', 'Vlad', False))

@pytest.mark.parametrize('task', tasks_to_try_2, task_to_try_3)
def test_function_count(task):
    task_id = tasks.add(task)
    task_get = tasks.get(task_id)
    t_count = tasks.count()
    assert t_count == 2
```

Передаю два таска, который я записываю. Один таск успешно записывается, а когда два передаю, то получаю ошибку такую:

```
In test_function_count: indirect fixture 'Task(summary='Situp', owner='slavik', done=True, id=None)' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Декоратор [`@pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.python.Metafunc.parametrize) принимает набор параметров теста только вторым аргументом, а вы передаете еще один аргумент:

```
Metafunc.parametrize(argnames, argvalues, indirect=False, ids=None, scope=None)
```

Получается, что второй набор попадает в аргумент `indirect`.

Просто объедините два набора тасков:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('task', tasks_to_try_2 + task_to_try_3)
```

Comment: есть ли сайт или что-то со всеми фикстурами и их параметрами?

Comment: @VyacheslavBondarev, ну есть документация https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html